# Is the following code valid syntax?

Tags: javascript

When I run this:

```
function Person(name) {
   this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype.intro = function () {
   console.log("Hello I am " + this.name);
};

var person = new Person("John");

var intro = person.intro; 
alert(intro());
```

It produces a message box that simply says "undefined". Why?

Comment: What is your question & are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

I think you're trying to ask :  *"If this a valid syntax , then why it doesn't work?"*

Valid ? Yes
Working ? No.

This line  :

```
var intro = person.intro;
```

Makes your code loose `this`.

Now ,  `this` is the global window object.

Hence you don't see the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to loose `this` to the global window object try it like this

```
function Person(name) {
   this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype.intro = function () {
   console.log("Hello I am " + this.name);
};

var person = new Person("John");

person.intro();
```